# Setting a local varaible on a .net user control, c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have a .net web form, back end in c#. I have a user control on that form, with a single local variable on the user control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MyControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="MyWebForm.MyControl" %>
<%= myvar %>
```

On the back end of the user control, I want to set that variable to something. Anything, doesn't matter, a string value. What's the easiest way to do this?

I recognize this is a relatively simple question and it may have beeen answered already. I did some searching on my own and could only find similar questions based on passing a variable from the parent page to the control and vice versa. I'm not trying to do that. Just trying to set that myvar to something. If I need to be pointed to an existing answer, I don't mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're even able to do this:

```
<%= myvar %>
```

Then presumably `myvar` is a class-level member which is at least `protected` or possibly `public`?  From within any given class, you can set a class-level member:

```
this.myvar = "some value";
```

If the member is `public` then you can also set it from other objects where you have a reference to that object:

```
someObject.myvar = "some value";
```

In this case if `myvar` is a class member on the user control and the containing page has an instance of that user control as a control on that page, then the containing page would simply set that value:

```
MyControl1.myvar = "some value";
```

Comment: I was forgetting the "this." prefix. That's what i was looking for. Truth be told, I vastly simplified what was going on in this application to not stray away from what I needed help with. But this answered my question.